# Is preparing Windows 8 XAML HubPages from several GridViews inside ScrollViewer the good approach?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'd like to get the effect visible on the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is. A GridView already has a ScrollViewer in itself, so multiple of them does not make sense. I would try to use a single GridView with [GroupStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyleselector.aspx)/[ItemContainerStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx)/[ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) implementations and DataTemplates to define each item. A less dynamic version might just be a ScrollViewer with Style set to HorizontalScrollViewerStyle, a horizontal StackPanel and a few VariableSizedWrapGrids - if you bind the GridView to some groups or other panels to define the content.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423) looks like a good sample based on the description (though the images seem to be missing for me).

Comment: Also you can use just regular WrapGrids or StackPanels for your sections depending on the layout.